# How to use expression in ngIf-else in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is my piece of code

```
<tr *ngFor="let sample of data; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
    <ng-container *ngIf="sample .configuration_type == 1; then thenBlock; else elseBlock"></ng-container>
       <ng-template #thenBlock>
           <td>{{sample.item_number}}</td>
           <td>{{sample.make}}</td>
           <td>{{sample.model}}</td>
       </ng-template>
       <ng-template #elseBlock>
           <td>{{sample.serial_number}}</td>
           <td>{{sample.capacity}}</td>
           <td>{{sample.model}}</td>
       </ng-template>
</tr>
```

Error it displays as

Can't bind to 'ngIfThen' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.
1. If 'ng-container' is an Angular component and it has 'ngIfThen' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ng-container' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("gFor="let sample of data; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">

Answer (score 2):

As the error says you cannot use ngFor and ngIf on the same tag, instead do this using ng-container,

```
<tr *ngFor="let sample of data; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
    <ng-container *ngIf="sample.configuration_type === 1">
        <td>{{sample.item_number}}</td>
        <td>{{sample.make}}</td>
        <td>{{sample.model}}</td>
        <td>{{bucket.class}}</td>
        <td>{{bucket.capacity}}</td>
    </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hey I need something like if else. I edited my code. Your code is giving me blank rows when condition is not met. Can you please check?

Answer (score 0):

> Before using any `structural` directives import the `CommonModule` from `@angular/common` into your module. Also `ngIfElse` is only available since version 4.0.0.

For the edited question: You can use `ngIf` with the else syntax to differentiate between the items.

But this inside your `tr` element:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="sample.configuration_type === 1; else elseBlock">
    <td>{{sample.item_number}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.make}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.model}}</td>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
    <td>{{sample.serial_number}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.capacity}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.model}}</td>
</ng-template>
```

Or when you want to use `ng-template` only:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="sample.configuration_type === 1" [ngIfElse]="elseBlock">
    <td>{{sample.item_number}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.make}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.model}}</td>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
    <td>{{sample.serial_number}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.capacity}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.model}}</td>
</ng-template>
```

You can find more info about structural directives at the angular [docs page](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives).

> For Angular version <4.0.0 ther's no `ngIfElse` directive. You have to do it like this:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="sample.configuration_type === 1">
    <td>{{sample.item_number}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.make}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.model}}</td>
</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="sample.configuration_type !== 1">
    <td>{{sample.serial_number}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.capacity}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.model}}</td>
</ng-template>
```

---

> **Note:** The below answer was for the initial question, OP edited it to achieve another goal.

You should filter the data inside your component, with for example the array `filter` method.

Example:

```
export class MyComponent {
    // ...
    public get filteredData() {
       return this.data.filter(sample => sample.configuration_type !== 1);
    }
    // ...
}
```

And then in your component use the `filteredData` to loop over:

```
<tr *ngFor="let sample of filteredData; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
    <td>{{sample.item_number}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.make}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.model}}</td>
    <td>{{bucket.class}}</td>
    <td>{{bucket.capacity}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: My requirement is I have to display both the data depending on the conditions. I need something like If-else

Comment: It was for your initial question.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: It throws the same error Can't bind to 'ngIfElse' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.

Comment: Did you import the `CommonModule` from `@angular/common` to your module which is declaring your component and what is your angular version?

Comment: I imported and my angular version is 3.4.0

Comment: There no 3.4.0 version of angular, only 2.x.x and 4.x.x.

Comment: I've mistaken that from my package.json initial lines...something like {
  "name": "Sing",
  "version": "3.4.0",
  "description": "Sing Dashboard App with Angular 2.0 Final Release support by Flatlogic"....}. It's 2 actually

Comment: `NgIfElse` directive is only available since angular version 4.0.0. You have to use `*ngIf` on both elements and invert it for the "elseBlock" element.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried the if-else method you mentioned in angular 2 earlier. But it's throwing error: Template parse errors:
'ng-template' is not a known element: I even imported common module already. Idk what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have imported the `CommonModule` in your AppModule imports.

> import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

```
@NgModule({

  imports: [
    // ... other modules    
    CommonModule
  ],
```

Here is a plunker link to demonstrate the if-then-else behavior: [**PLUNKER DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/XczPUPLHPnbNnD2VC2aV?p=preview)